# C++ Compile Error: gnu_printf is an unrecognized format function type

Tags: c++, printf, compiler-warnings

When compiling I am getting the same warning on 3 different lines of code in a .h file such as this:

> warning `gnu_printf` is an unrecognized format function type

My flags look like this:

> CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter \

Examples of the three lines of code producing this error below:

```
int ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(1,2) OutputDebugStringF(const char* pszFormat, ...);

std::string ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(1,3) real_strprintf(const char *format, int dummy, ...);

bool ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(1,2) error(const char *format, ...);
```

I have many other uses of `printf()` in this file that are not producing any errors. I am a bit confused on the error in the formatting.

Comment: What is `ATTR_WARN_PRINTF()`?

Comment: @Azeem `/* This GNU C extension enables the compiler to check the format string against the parameters provided.
 * X is the number of the "format string" parameter, and Y is the number of the first variadic parameter.
 * Parameters count from 1.
 */
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(X,Y) __attribute__((format(gnu_printf,X,Y)))
#else
#define ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(X,Y)
#endif`

Comment: Right. Can you please post a minimal code example causing this warning? One that could be compiled in isolation. Thanks.

Comment: You can look around lines 172-198 to see where the errors are stemming from. [link](https://github.com/peercoin/peercoin/blob/master/src/util.h)

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Clang?  Something on MinGW?  What version?

Comment: I am trying to compile the makefile.osx to create a headless daemon for MAC and I also have to compile the QT.pro file to create a QT wallet for mac. I am compiling on MAC OS X 10.5.8 leopard using different dependencies and old dependencies like. Problem is I used macports and it has been difficult to revert some dependencies back to older versions argh. I am compiling native in terminal with gcc6.4, db48, boost 1.66. If you want to know any specific dependency let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the failing code is:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__ 
#define ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(X,Y) __attribute__((format(gnu_printf,X,Y))) 
#else 
#define ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(X,Y)
#endif
int ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(1,2) OutputDebugStringF(const char* pszFormat, ...);

std::string ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(1,3) real_strprintf(const char *format, int dummy, ...);

bool ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(1,2) error(const char *format, ...);
```

It seems that this works on any gcc between versions 4.4.7 and gcc trunk (9.0.0). 
GCC 4.1.2 fails with:

```
<source>:7: warning: 'gnu_printf' is an unrecognized format function type
```

Also, clang always fails on this:

```
<source>:7:5: warning: 'format' attribute argument not supported: gnu_printf [-Wignored-attributes]
```

But from the original question it seems that the issue with a GCC which is too old. To fix this, check GCC version number:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && ((__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__>= 4) || __GNUC__ > 4)
#  define ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(X,Y) __attribute__((format(gnu_printf,X,Y))) 
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#  define ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(X,Y) __attribute__((format(printf,X,Y))) 
#else 
#  define ATTR_WARN_PRINTF(X,Y)
#endif
```

Maybe even it is better to restrict the format to `printf` instead of `gnu_printf`, and so the above condition can be simplified.

**EDIT:** As can be found on GCC history, the `gnu_printf` format was added in gcc-4.4.0
[commit r133365](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-cvs/2008-03/msg00584.html). From what I understand, it is merely an alias to `printf`, and the gnu prefix was added to allow differentiation between `printf` of different compilers, such as possibly `ms_printf`.